# coordinate transformation of the Laplace Beltrami Operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, analytic-geometry, elliptic-equations

My Laplace-Beltrami operator isn't transforming correctly under a change of coordinates. What am I doing wrong?

---

The Laplace-Betrami operator has the following expressing in local coordinates of a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$,
\begin{align}
\Delta f(x) = g^{ij}(x) \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} + g^{jk}\Gamma^i_{jk} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i},
\end{align}
where $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ are Christoffel symbols. Written in this way, it is clear that the Laplace-Beltrami operator is a second-order elliptic operator on the manifold.

Many books such as [Markov Processes by Dynkin](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662000335) (page 151) or [Functional Analysis by Yosida](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540586548) (page 426) state that the coefficient functions of elliptic operators must transform in a prescribed way in order to give a consistent result on the manifold. Namely, consider an elliptic operator of the form (written in local coordinates $x$)
\begin{align}
Af(x) = b^i(x) \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} + a^{ij}(x) \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}.
\end{align}
Then in another coordinate system $\tilde{x}$ the coefficient functions transform as
\begin{align}
\tilde{b}^i(x) &= b^k(x) \frac{\partial \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_k} + a^{kl}(x)\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_k\partial x_l} \\\\
\tilde{a}^{ij}(x) &= a^{kl}(x) \frac{\partial \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial \tilde{x}_j}{\partial x_l}.
\end{align}
The Laplace-Beltrami operator should then obey this transformation rule with $a^{ij} =g^{ij}$ and $b^i = g^{jk}\Gamma^i_{jk}$. The fact that $g^{ij}$ obeys the correct transformation rule is apparent; however, I am having a hard time seeing that $g^{jk}\Gamma^i_{jk}$ obeys the correct transformation.

---

What I want to show is that
\begin{align}
\tilde{g}^{jk}\tilde{\Gamma}^i_{jk} = g^{pq}\Gamma^k_{pq} \frac{\partial \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_k} + g^{pq}\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{x}_p}{\partial x_k\partial x_q}
\end{align}

I know that the transformation rule for the Christoffel symbols is as follows:
\begin{align}
    \tilde{\Gamma}^i_{jk} &= \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial\tilde{x_j}}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial\tilde{x}_k} \Gamma_{pq}^r \frac{\tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_r} + \frac{\partial^2 x_r}{\partial \tilde{x}_j\partial \tilde{x}_k} \frac{\partial \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_r} \\
    &= \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial\tilde{x_j}}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial\tilde{x}_k} \Gamma_{pq}^r \frac{\tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_r} - \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial \tilde{x}_j} \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_p\partial x_q} \frac{\partial x_q}{\partial \tilde{x}_k}
\end{align}
If I multiply both sides by $\tilde{g}^{jk}$ and use the transformation law of the inverse metric in coordinates, I obtain,
\begin{align}
    \tilde{g}^{jk} \tilde{\Gamma}^i_{jk} &=  \tilde{g}^{jk} \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial\tilde{x_j}}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial\tilde{x}_k} \Gamma_{pq}^r \frac{\tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_r} - \tilde{g}^{jk}\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial \tilde{x}_j} \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_p\partial x_q} \frac{\partial x_q}{\partial \tilde{x}_k} \\
    &= g^{pq} \Gamma_{pq}^r \frac{\tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_r} - g^{pq} \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{x}_i}{\partial x_p\partial x_q}.
\end{align}
This is very nearly what I wanted to show, but differs from the expected result by a negative sign in the second term. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this is an old question, this could hopefully help someone in the future.

If we compute the Laplacian from its coordinate-free definition $\Delta f = \mathrm{tr}~\nabla (\mathrm{grad}~u)$ and we consider the definition of the Christoffel symbols, we arrive at
$$
\Delta u
=
(\partial_i\partial_ju)g^{ij}
+
(\partial_iu)\partial_j(g^{ij})
+
(\partial_iu)g^{ij}\Gamma_{kj}^k.
$$

This is still not quite the expression you presented us, so we have to use the old trick $g^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$ and consider the expression of the Christoffel symbols in terms of the coefficients of the metric
$$
\Gamma_{jk}^i
=
\frac{g^{im}}{2}
\left[
\partial_j(g_{mk})
+
\partial_k(g_{mj})
-
\partial_m(g_{jk})
\right]
$$
in order to re-write such expression as
$$
\Delta u
=
(\partial_i\partial_ju)g^{ij}
-
(\partial_iu)g^{jk}\Gamma_{jk}^i.
$$

As this matches the expression of the Laplace-Beltrami Operator given, for example, in [List of formulas in Riemannian geometry - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Gradient,_divergence,_Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator), then I believe your mistake was the local expression that you considered the Laplace-Beltrami Operator to have, and not your computations.