# Laplace-Beltrami operator in coordinates

Tags: riemannian-geometry, laplacian, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I know that on a Lorentzian manifold the Laplace-Beltrami operator of a function $\phi\in C^\infty(M)$ is defined as
$$
\triangle_g \phi = \text{div}(\text{grad}\phi).
$$
Now I've come across the following expression in local coordiantes
$$
\triangle_g \phi = g^{\alpha\beta}(\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\phi+\Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\lambda\phi)
$$
but I was not able to derive it (nor to find a derivation online). Why is this expression true? How to derive it from the definition?

(I am also not sure if the signs are correct the way I wrote it.)

Comment: See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174164/coordinate-transformation-of-the-laplace-beltrami-operator).

Comment: Any decent textbook on Riemannian geometry should have both definitions and the derivation of it. DoCarmo is an example.